Transform character string with ranges into numeric vector in R
I have a dataframe with a column containing ranges of values, as well as single values, like in the following:
x <- c("a","b")
y <- c("1:3,7","9")

dat <- data.frame("char"=x,"range"=y)

> dat
  char range
1    a 1:3,7
2    b     9

What I need to do is transform the range column so that all the values contained in the ranges show up:
> dat2
  char   range
1    a 1,2,3,7
2    b       9

I have made progress thanks to the solution provided in this very similar question:
v1 <- c("1:3")

unlist(lapply(v1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))

[1] 1 2 3 9

But this only gets me so far because of course if I pass a vector which also has single values, like my original range column, it will throw an error:
v1 <- c("1:3,7","9")

unlist(lapply(v1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))

Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:4: unexpected ','
1: 1:3,
^

In addition, I can't automatically apply this solution to the dataframe column, because it returns separate numeric values and I need a character string. Any help is appreciated.
EDIT 
Thanks to everyone for the very useful comments!

The following modification gives you what you want...
v1 <- c("1:3,7","9")

unlist(lapply(v1, function(x) paste(eval(parse(text=paste0("c(",x,")"))), 
                                    collapse = ",")))

[1] "1,2,3,7" "9" 


Very similar to @Andrew Gustar's answer:
> sapply(v1, \(x) toString(eval(parse(text=paste0("c(",x,")")))))
       1:3,7            9 
"1, 2, 3, 7"          "9"


Maybe try this method, which uses sapply and doesn't rely on eval:
sapply(strsplit(v1, ","), function(x) paste(unlist(sapply(strsplit(x, ":"),
                          function(y) if(length(y)==2) seq(as.integer(y[1]),as.integer(y[2]))
                          else as.integer(y))), collapse=","))


Use gsubfn to match digits, colon and digits and then transform that using the function specified in formula notation replacing the matched string. Note that seq can take string arguments and interpret them as numeric.
library(dplyr)
library(gsubfn)

dat %>%
 mutate(range=gsubfn("(\\d+):(\\d+)", ~paste(seq(x,y), collapse=","), range))

giving
  char   range
1    a 1,2,3,7
2    b       9

